# REGEX - (using Python 3.5) - finding strings in file

Tags: python, regex

I have a .msg outlook file I'm opening and need to extract some specific data from it. I'm still a little new to regex and am having trouble finding what I need.

Below is the data from the file, it contains some tabs it seems just fyi:

```
NEWS ID:    918273/1
TITLE:  News Platform Solution Overview (CNN) (US English Session)
ACCOUNT:    supernewsplatformacct (55712)

Your request has been completed.

Output Format   MP4

Please click on the "Download File" link below to access the download page.

Download File <http://news.downloadwebsitefake.com/newsid/file1294757493292848575.mp4>
```

I need:

`918273` -from- `NEWS ID:    918273/1`

`News Platform Solution Overview (CNN) (US English Session)` -from- `TITLE:  News Platform Solution Overview (CNN) (US English Session)`

`supernewsplatformacct` -from- `ACCOUNT:    supernewsplatformacct (55712)`

`http://news.downloadwebsitefake.com/newsid/file1294757493292848575.mp4` -from- `Download File <http://news.downloadwebsitefake.com/newsid/file1294757493292848575.mp4>`

I'm trying

`[\n\r][ \t]*NEWS ID:[ \t]*([^\n\r]*)`

But with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Use `\s` (whitespace) instead of combinations of space, tab, and `\r / \n`. Just to make things cleaner. Why does your regex start with `[\n\r]`? And can you show us some python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\n))[^:<\n]*[:<](.*)
```

You can use this with `re.findall`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/d7RPNB/2

Comment: while this is close the last item he wanted was `http://news.downloadwebsitefake.com/newsid/file1294757493292848575.mp4` and you only get `//news......`

Comment: I see the demo and that's what I'm saying is it doesn't match his requirements exactly, here is a slightly modified version which gets the `http://....`, I think something with named groups where he has to check if it's a url or not would work `(?:^|(?<=\n))[^:\n]*[^http]:\s*(?P<info>.*)|(?P<url>http:.*)>`

Comment: I modified yours to not get extras space or `>` at the end, check https://regex101.com/r/WJkRK5/1

Answer (score 0):

```
msg = """NEWS ID:    918273/1
TITLE:  News Platform Solution Overview (CNN) (US English Session)
ACCOUNT:    supernewsplatformacct (55712)

Your request has been completed.

Output Format   MP4

Please click on the "Download File" link below to access the download page.

Download File <http://news.downloadwebsitefake.com/newsid/file1294757493292848575.mp4>"""
import re
regex = r'[^:]+:\s+(.*)$|[^<]+<([^>]+)>'
matches = [re.match(regex, i).group(1) or re.match(regex, i).group(2) for i in msg.split('\n') if i and re.match(regex, i)]
print(matches)
```